# Please check the error in my code for increment of an integer

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, runtime-error

Here I have written a code for accepting an integer from user and increasing it by one globally using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inc(int *a)
{
    *a=*a+1;
    return *a;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    int *p;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    p=&a;
    printf("%d\n", inc(*p));
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

But when I run the program and enter a value for a, it terminates without giving any output. Please tell where I have erred and help to improve the code.

Comment: You're passing the entered integer value as though it's a pointer. Don't dereference `p`: `printf("%d\n", inc(p));`

Comment: You should turn up your compiler warnings. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`. It should show you some warning about passing incorrect parameter type to `inc`. You pass `int` while it expects `int*`. `*p` points to `a` which does not hold a valid address.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Yup. `warning: passing argument 1 of 'inc' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` and `note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'`

Comment: @FredLarson Oh, that works now. Sorry for the mistake and thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call of the function `inc`

```
printf("%d\n", inc(*p));
```

you are passing an object of the type `int` (`*p`) instead of a pointer as required by the function declaration

You need to write

```
printf("%d\n", inc(p));
```

Comment: Sorry, that was silly of me. Thanks for helping out.